# React toggle state fired only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Root tag `App` in sandbox looks as:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react'

export default function App() {
    let [dark, setDark] = useState(true)

    const toggleDark = useCallback(() => {
        setDark(!dark)
    }, []);

    return (
        <main>
            <p onClick={toggleDark}>{dark ? 'dark mode' : 'light mode'}</p>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Initial page content - "dark mode".

Press on it, changed to "light mode".

Press again on "light mode" - nothing changed. Seems state of App changed only once.

How to force state changed every time I click on <p> ?

You can see full sample at [Replit sandbox](https://replit.com/@vbulash/ToggleState#src/App.jsx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `dark` as dependency to the `useCallback`. Otherwise the function is cached and always assumes that `dark` has the initial value of `true`:

```
const toggleDark = useCallback(() => {
        setDark(!dark)
    }, [dark]); // add dark as dependency here
```